# How do you match zero or one character in the "-name" option of the "find" command?

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression, wildcards

For instance, want to match all files in this directory and sub-directories that end with `.ly` or `.ily`.  So far, `find . -name "*.*ly" -print` is the closest I can get but this could potentially find files names I don't want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-o` option, which is an "or" option.

The simplest version would be

```
find . -name '*.ly' -o -name '*.ily'
```

This works because `-print` is the default action.

But if the `-print` was just an example then you might need to group the two clauses together

```
find . \( -name '*.ly' -o -name '*.ily' \) -print
```

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` globs have a `**/` recursive globbing operator and glob qualifiers so can do most of what `find` can do. Zero-or-one of something, aka *optional* something can be done with `(|something)` there (nothing or *something*), though there's also a `(#cX,Y)` similar to regex `{X,Y}` as an arbitrary interval operator (needs `set -o extendedglob`):

```
print -rC1 -- **/*.(|i)ly(N)
```

Would have the advantage over the `find` equivalent of giving you a sorted list, skipping hidden files (use the `D` qualifier if you want them), avoiding the `./` prefix, working with arbitrary file names (many `find`  implementations including GNU `find` choke on file names that are not valid text in  the user's locale) and generally makes it easier and safer to work with the list of files if you need more than printing them.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `-regex` with those `find` implementations that support it:

With [GNU `find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```bash
find -regex '.*\.i?ly'
# or the full command
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.i?ly'
```

With [BSD `find`](https://man.openbsd.org/find.1):

```bash
find -E . -regex '.*\.i?ly'
```

The `-regex` option matches the whole path and is anchored at both start and end, so you need `.*` at the beginning and don't need `$` at the end.

`?` is an *extended* regular expression operator (as in `grep -E`) that matches 0 or 1 of the preceding atom, here `i`. It's not available in basic regular expressions¹, so you need the `-E` in BSD `find`. In GNU `find` (at least in current versions), the default regex are neither basic nor extended regex, but some regex variant from some ancient version of emacs, where `?` *is* supported. So that `-regextype posix-extended` is not necessary in this case here.

---

<sup>¹ `\{0,1\}` has been added to BREs as an equivalent of ERE `?` later though.</sup>

Comment: This doesn't seem to exclude files ending in e.g. `.ely`.

Comment: use `.*\.i?ly$` rather than `.*/.*\..?ly`.   `./*/.*` can be reduced to just `.*` (filenames output from find will always have a path), `i?` restricts it to an optional `i` after the `.` rather than any character, and the `$` anchors the `ly` to the end of the filename (otherwise it will match *anywhere* in the filename - e.g. it would match "i.can.fly.txt")

Comment: @cas it matches the whole path so you don't actually need `$`