# Copy multiple files by filenames in subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, scripting, filenames

I can do the following to copy a file from subdirectories.

`find . -name "file1.txt" -type f -exec cp {} ./distfolder \;`

How do I change this code to copy multiple files (`file1.txt, file5.txt, file6.txt`) by their names from subdirectories?

Simply doing `find . -name "file1.txt, file5.txt, file6.txt" -type f -exec cp {} ./distfolder \;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-name` test accepts a POSIX filename generation pattern, so

```
find . -name "file[156].txt"
```

For more complex cases, tests may be chained with the logical conjunction `-o`

```
find . \( -name "file1.txt" -o -name "file5.txt" -o -name "file6.txt" \)
```

See also this recent question [How do you match zero or one character in the "-name" option of the "find" command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746567/how-do-you-match-zero-or-one-character-in-the-name-option-of-the-find-comma)